# how to get malayalam fonts working with flutter app?

Tags: flutter, fonts

Can you help me with how to type Malayalam font in the flutter App? I only found 'Baloo Chettan 2' from Google Fonts which is working but I don't want that font. I have some other fonts like Karthika.tff, Keraleeyam.tff. But those do not seem to be working. Can someone assist me? (I don't want FML or ML TT fonts btw because I think it will make it hard to read on content updation in future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To type malayalam, you can use the fonts like FML or ML TT fonts that are available for download. Using FML/ML TT Malayalam fonts are tottally different and you need to do following things to make it work.

1. Download ML TT / FML Malayalam Font .tff file and add it as usual. (check Andrey Gritsay's reply)
2. Go to website https://kuttipencil.in/google/
   Type your desired text and convert it to FML / ML TT
3. You will get a code like this 'XjhgdhK', but this code will get actual malayalam look when we set it to a FML font.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question: How can we integrate this function into our Flutter app?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find needed font in `google_fonts` package then you have to add `.ttf` files into your project manually.

To do so you have to provide info about those fonts in `pubspec.yaml` file like so:

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
  fonts:
    - family: Inter
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-Thin.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-ExtraLight.ttf
          weight: 200
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-ExtraBold.ttf
          weight: 800
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-Black.ttf
          weight: 900
```

then you need to provide a `TextStyle` to your `Text` widget:

```dart
final style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Inter');
Text('Some text', style: style);
```

Note that `fontFamily` should match `family` in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: No brother, I already added .tff files but it doesnot seems to make any change in the app. but If i use the font in my computer with some other softwares like paint and choose the font it works. so .tff file is working fine but not working only in flutter app.

Comment: Did you do exactly what I'd written? I mean created `assets/fonts` directory **near** `lib` folder and not in it, provided style and accomplished `flutter pug get`?

Comment: yes brother, english fonts working. but malayalam font not working

Comment: Also after accomplishing all these steps you need to stop and run again your app. And if  it works with English and not with your language then you should find out another font files

Comment: Hello brother, I found it working as I missed to restart the full app after adding some fonts. Now most fonts working and some fonts which is not working as maybe because of the problem. thank you.